# Use container name as var to stream logs to cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm trying to stream kubernetes logs to cloudwatch using awslogs agent. Below is my config. it works except that i have multiple pods running on my EC2. How can i get all the pod logs and distinguish between them?

```
[app]
datetime_format = %b %d %H:%M:%S
file = /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/150/fs/var/log/app.log
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = {instance_id}-myapp
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = /aws/k8/myapp
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, you can use a unique identifier for each pod in the log_stream_name parameter of your AWSLogs agent configuration file. You can use the *{container_id}* field, which will be unique for each pod, or the *{container_name}* field, which can be set to a meaningful value that identifies the pod.

For example, you could add the {container_id} field to your configuration file like this:

```
[app]
datetime_format = %b %d %H:%M:%S
file = /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/150/fs/var/log/app.log
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = {instance_id}-myapp-{container_id}
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = /aws/k8/myapp
```

This would create a unique log stream for each pod based on its container ID.

Alternatively, you could use the {container_name} field like this:

```
[app]
datetime_format = %b %d %H:%M:%S
file = /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.snapshotter.v1.overlayfs/snapshots/150/fs/var/log/app.log
buffer_duration = 5000
log_stream_name = {instance_id}-myapp-{container_name}
initial_position = start_of_file
log_group_name = /aws/k8/myapp
```

This would create a unique log stream for each pod based on its container name. Just make sure each pod has a unique name to avoid conflicts.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Is {container_id} or {container_name} a pre-defined variable? It doesn't populate the variable when used as is.